# Is there a special name for the function that is non-zero (one) only at one point?

Tags: functions

Does this function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,\, \text{for }x\neq a\\ 1,\,\text{for }x=a\end{cases}, \text{where}\ a\in\mathbb R.$$

have a special name in mathematics?

note: I know it is either not delta "function", or the domain discrete version, the impulse function.

Comment: Indicator function?

Comment: @HarryPetyt Yes, to be exact, $1_{\{a\}}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: @HarryPetyt thanks.